# The configuration parameter “componentType” is a required for “advanced_pricing_modal” component. Magento 2.1.7 Clean Install

Tags: product, configurable-product, products, inventory, magento-2.1.7

I'm getting an error when editing or creating a new product: The configuration parameter "componentType" is a required for "advanced_inventory_modal" component.

This is not an upgraded Magento install - the error showed up after the weekend. I'm running the cron scripts below:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -d memory_limit=1024M /home/.../public_html/beta/bin/magento index:reindex
/usr/local/bin/php -d memory_limit=1024M /home/.../public_html/beta/bin/magento cron:run
/usr/local/bin/php -d memory_limit=1024M /home/.../public_html/beta/bin/magento cache:clean
/usr/local/bin/php -d memory_limit=1024M /home/.../public_html/beta/bin/magento cache:flush
```

The full error output below:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:99:"The configuration parameter "componentType" is a required for "advanced_inventory_modal" component.";i:1;s:7195:"#0 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(362): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem(Array, Array, false)
#1 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(272): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem(Array, Array, false)
#2 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(164): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadata('product_form', Array, false)
#3 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(125): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('product_form', NULL, Array)
#4 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'product_form', Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
#5 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#6 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#7 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#8 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#9 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#10 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(244): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#11 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(859): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#12 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php(59): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('menu')
#13 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Edit.php(69): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog...')
#14 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit->execute()
#15 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#18 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#19 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#22 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /home/.../public_html/beta/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#25 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#28 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#29 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /home/.../public_html/beta/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#32 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 /home/.../public_html/beta/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#34 /home/lscoguar/public_html/beta/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#35 {main}";s:3:"url";s:104:"/.../catalog/product/edit/id/701/key/9a811e1ecc44d2c45e3885b5914d94b61f6635ed883f2e4c03abf6120f707fba/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Comment: I was able to print_r the $data that's throwing the exception.  It's seems to be something around the configuration of stock and inventory quantities.  https://pastebin.com/j6SLhMSw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered this is a data corruption issue.  I re-installed Magento and re-importing catalog data via CSV.  This is resolved.